# Invalid hook call trying to make an axios get request in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm recreating a simple weather app with react and am having a lot of trouble creating a very simple API call. I've tried a plethora of methods on here, youtube, etc and continuously get errors. The current code I have is:

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import { Home } from '../components/Home'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

var weatherApiRootUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org';
var weatherApiKey = 'd91f911bcf2c0f925fb6535547a5ddc9';


//function to generate weather URL. fetches lat/lon and creates new url
function GetWeatherUrl(loc){
  const [weatherLink, setWeatherLink] = useState("");

  const getCoordinates = () => {
    Axios.get(`${weatherApiRootUrl}/geo/1.0/direct?q=${loc}&limit=5&appid=${weatherApiKey}`).then(
      (response)=>{
        console.log(response);
        setWeatherLink(`${weatherApiRootUrl}/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${response.data.lat}&lon=${response.data.lon}&units=imperial&exclude=minutely,hourly&appid=${weatherApiKey}`);
      }
    );
  };
return(
  <div>
    {weatherLink}
  </div>
);
  
}

export{
  GetWeatherUrl
}
```

The purpose of this file is just to use the user input (a city name designed by variable loc) to fetch lat/lon coordinates of the inputted city as that data is needed for the second link that fetches weather information. The user input is handled from another component and works fine.

All I intend for this code to do is fetch latitude and longitude data using `loc` and use those numbers to generate the new link that fetches weather data. The weather data will be done with a different api call on another file. The working method of this current file should be useable for the future file meant to fetch weather so this is kind of two birds in one stone.

I need the `weatherLink` generated to be able to be exported to do this so I would really prefer a solution allowing that please. I originally was going to just export the raw lat/lon data and use them for the call in the new file as how I did with `loc` here but I decided returning a completed link as a string would maybe be easier. Really would appreciate someone's help on this it's been frustrating me for way longer than it should!

Not really needed but here's the non-react version of the site if it helps: https://giovannimalcolm.github.io/weather-dashboard/

Comment: Is this supposed to be a function that returns a value, or a component? Where is this being used? The easiest way to fix this is to make this a component, and use a `useEffect` function with an empty depedency array to call it on load.

Comment: It should return a string using data pulled from the API call. This is a standalone service file for purely this get request. What I've posted is the entire file. Could you please show me a working example (with my code please) of what you're suggesting? I've previously tried solutions involving useEffect but have not been successful. "Loc" can be just any city name

Comment: There is no reason why it should be a React component. Can't it be just a function that returns a string? It feels like you're unnecessarily complicating the issue at hand.

Comment: I should have clarified that he was trying to use it as a function, but had component logic in it. So he either had to invoke the function where he wants in the component that isn't listed, or convert this into a component that he can inject where he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily solved without needing to use React at all, since it is not a component and doesn't have any rendering logic in itself per se:

```
import Axios from 'axios';

const weatherApiRootUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org';
const weatherApiKey = 'd91f911bcf2c0f925fb6535547a5ddc9';

export async function GetWeatherUrl(loc) {
    const response = await Axios.get(`${weatherApiRootUrl}/geo/1.0/direct?q=${loc}&limit=5&appid=${weatherApiKey}`);
    return `${weatherApiRootUrl}/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${response.data.lat}&lon=${response.data.lon}&units=imperial&exclude=minutely,hourly&appid=${weatherApiKey}`;
}
```

Then in places where you need to use the weather URL, you need to remember that `GetWeatherUrl` returns a **promise**, so you've got to await it (or handle it like any other promise):

```
const myFn = async () => {
    const weatherUrl = await GetWeatherUrl(loc);
    const weatherUrlData = await Axios.get(weatherUrl);
};

myFn();
```

Comment: Thanks, Terry! Had to step out but this looks like it will work. However, right after this I need to make the second API call file which does have a bit of rendering logic. In this case would using the useEffect be necessary? I’d need to pull several variables (weather info as shown in the link) from the object returned to be used for rendering. Just want to make sure I’m understanding this right

Comment: You would set state based on the weatherUrlData being returned, and pass that into whatever rendering component you wanted. It depends on the shape of the object being returned, as well as how you handle the rendering. My guess would be you have those cards as a component, and you map over the results, passing the nested object for each day into the rendering component for each card. Post some code and we can help you with that. Probably linking to another question.

Comment: @JoelHager Looking for some clarification on your method. I’ve posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71242562/using-api-data-in-multiple-components-to-conditionally-render . Basically just trying to figure out how I can use the API data in multiple components? I currently have the API call functions be called in the Home component since it’s being used for conditional rendering but I need the data to render in other components