# Using API data in multiple components to conditionally render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the same app/continuation of this previous question: [Invalid hook call trying to make an axios get request in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71189776/invalid-hook-call-trying-to-make-an-axios-get-request-in-react)

Currently, I'm trying to figure out the best way to conditionally render a component and pass values from my API calls to it. I'll try to explain the current set up of the app the best I can. Here is a link of the non-react version for some visuals: https://giovannimalcolm.github.io/weather-dashboard/

I plan to have a component for the page before any input is submitted. The component I'm working on now is for the current weather box that appears once a city is submitted. I will make a third component for the five forecast cards below the aforementioned.

Currently, in the Home component, I have a onClick on the search button to show the current weather component when clicked. I will probably change this to onSubmit and later add an autocomplete function to the search box for not only more precise results but to also prevent submissions of poor formatting or null submissions. I believe the weather will data will always return with something in this case. The Home component is shown below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Weather} from '../components/TodaysWeather'
import { getWeatherData } from '../service/getWeather';
import { GetWeatherUrl } from '../service/getWeatherUrl';

export class Home extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        location: "",
        showWeather: false
    };
    this.locationChange = this.locationChange.bind(this);
}

 onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

locationChange(e){
    this.setState({
        location: e.target.value
    });
}

_showWeather = async (bool) => {
    this.setState({
        showWeather: bool
    });
    await getWeatherData(this.state.location)
console.log(await GetWeatherUrl(this.state.location))
}

componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log(this.state)
}


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <header className="main-header">
                    <h1>Weather Dashboard</h1>
                </header>

                <div className="container-fluid" style={{ maxWidth: '1400px' }}>
                    <div className="row">
                        <aside className="col-lg-3 pb-3">
                            <h2 id="sidebar-title">Search for a City:</h2>

                            <form onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e)} id="citySearch">
                                <div className="input-group">
                                    <input
                                        className="form-control"
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="City Here"
                                        id="city-input"
                                        onChange={this.locationChange }
                                    />

                                    <div className="input-group-append"></div>
                                </div>

                                <button
                                    type="submit"
                                    className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                                    id="sidebar-btn"
                                    onClick={this._showWeather.bind(null,true)}
                                >
                                    Search
                                </button>
                            </form>
                            <div id="history"></div>
                        </aside>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
               
            </div>

        )


    }

}
```

I have API calls to get the weather data in a separate "service" folder. These are called in the Home component in the `_showweather` function. What I need help with is figuring out the best way to capture the data from the API call in Home and send it over to the TodaysWeather component (and later the Forecast component) so it can be used for conditionally rendering via states and rendering in the virtual DOM.

I've considered doing the API call in the TodaysWeather component as shown below but this won't work as I need the data to be pulled before any rendering.

```
import { GetWeatherUrl } from "../service/getWeatherUrl";
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export class Weather extends Component {

    state = {
        loading: true,
        weather: []
    }

async componentDidMount(){
    const res = await Axios.get(GetWeatherUrl());
    this.setState({weather: res.data, loading: false})
    console.log(this.state.weather);
}


render(){
   
    return( 
        <div>
            <div className="col-lg-9 pb-3">
        <section id="presentDay" className="todaysWeather">
            <div className="todaysWeather-body">
                <h2 className="h3 today-title"> San Diego <img className="weather-img" src="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/03d.png" alt="scattered clouds" /></h2>
                <p className="today-txt">Temp: </p>
                <p className="today-txt">Wind: 11.5 MPH</p>
                <p className="today-txt">Humidity: 61 %</p>
                <p>UV  Index: <button className="uvi-btn wary-uvi">3.1</button>
                </p></div>
        </section>
        </div>
        </div>

    )

}

}
```

Is there a better way to set this all up? Please ignore the strings in the render section, it only was there for debugging.

Comment: React only way would probably be to have a parent component that gets the data, sets the state, and passes that data to its child component through props/

Comment: If you want to share data across components (i.e. throughout the app), perhaps you can consider using Redux?

Comment: There is no reason to set up Redux or a context to just pass one prop down. React even says there's nothing wrong with drilling a few props down if it's not everywhere in your app.

Comment: Set conditional logic to only start trying to render the children components if the response has come back from Axios. Think `!!data && <Childcomponent data={data} />` I'd also *highly* suggest you look into using functional components. They're the future-facing way to do it, so it's best to get used to that approach.